# How do I Export XML in Wordpress with a specific order of meta data?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss, xml-rpc

In Wordpress I need to export XML in a specific order with specific tags.

For example I only want to show posts where the meta-data of a post is  `"sold"="no"`

Also, I need to change the order and tags of the XML to something like this:

```
<MakeName> (STRING) </MakeName>
<Mileage> (INTEGER) </Mileage>
<ModelName> (STRING) </ModelName>
```

Because right now it shows as:

```
<miles> (INTEGER) </miles>
<model> (STRING) </model>
<make> (STRING) </make>
```

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do this or I just need to rewrite something with the XML-RPC WordPress API?

Forgive my newbness, and thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you exporting the XML? A plugin? Post the code you have now and someone will be able to show you how to alter it.

Comment: Right now I don't have any code. I tried getting:
get_post_meta( $page_id, "", ""); but that only gives me part of it.

Comment: You said you got to something like this... `<miles> (INTEGER) </miles>`. If you post exactly how you got to that someone will be able to tell you how to change the order and rename the XML elements. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: No it's ok. I'm having a trouble explaining it. My goal is to get `<miles> (INTEGER) </miles>` I found the first example in "website.com/feed", because Wordpress sets up an RSS already. Then I am getting the second example from the client, because that is what they are asking for. They just sent me a PDF so no coding was involved that way either.